# where should i locate xml file if i want to parse it inside java servlet

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I want to parse xml file inside servlet, but an exception happen which JVM cannot specify the xml file location.

here's the exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: FormFieldsNames.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

i tried to put the xml file in the project direction, java src package, and inside the package of servlets but all of these tries get the same result.

where should i locate xml file , please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common problem with reading files from the classpath is getting the location correct in your WAR file.

In Java, a servlet called MyServlet could reference the file like this

```
InputStream is=MyServlet.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/file/example.txt")
```

which will locate a file stored under

```
WEB-INF/classes/path/to/file/example.txt
```

Note the leading / which often catches people out.

It is possible for the application container to read from the local file system (say if you wanted to get hold of external properties and didn't want to use JNDI). For that you'd use the usual file access process:

```
InputStream fis = FileInputStream(new File("/usr/share/myapp/another-example.txt"));
```

Of course, if you want to point DOM at it then MyServlet could contain the following:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputStream is = MyServlet.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/my/example.xml");
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(is));
// And start exploring the NodeList...
NodeList nodeList = document.getFirstChild().getChildNodes();
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: @Gray Rowe- what if i don't want to make object from servlet ???
how can i use this MyServlet.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/my/example.xml");

Comment: @Alaa The above approach works for any class. Your servlet could just call into an instance of the class that handles the lookup, just replace the MyServlet with the appropriate class name.

Comment: it works , i need to specify the xml location inside the servlet so i use : InputStream fis=this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/FormFieldsNames.xml"); Many thanx

Comment: it struts `getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);` worked for me. so i cant directly create an InputStream if the file inside the project. Is there is some conceptual explanation for this.?

Comment: @Saif An [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) is an abstract class. Typically you rely on a factory method to create an implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The usual locations are:

- `WEB-INF/` - obtained by `getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(..)`
- `WEB-INF/classes`- obtained by either the above, or `getClass().getResourceAsStream(..)`

Comment: @Bozho- I tried both but i used 
 XMLStreamReader xmlReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(fileName)); to read the XML file then processing it via STAX, but the same exception !!

Comment: @Alaa - you are passing a filename. I never wrote something like that. I wrote how to obtain an `InputStream`. You can obtain a reader from a straem via `InputStreamReader`. Use it.

Comment: @Bozho- i pass the InputSream as a parameter, but I was thinking that passing file name may be more usable!! what do u think?

Comment: @Alaa - usable for who? Passing an inputStream is widely used. Have in mind that war files may be run unexploded - then you don't have a physical file.

Comment: @Bozho -war files contains xml file within web component,so what do mean with "then you don't have a physical file" ?? where xml will be loaded??and about input stream, i knew that it's object to read any file and loaded it into memory?so do u mean that i better to make object cashing?

Comment: @Bozho -  u asked it will be usable for who. for me for later frocessing for such xml files,By sending InputStreamReader to the function ,u make seperation of where to read the file and where to parse it,doesn't it?? This is just my point of view, and i'll be happy to know ur opinion too.

Answer (score 1):

If you include it in your jar/war file, you should be able to load it easily with `Class.getResourceAsStream` or `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`. Do that rather than trying to load it as an actual *file* on the file system.